# clear DOM cache when clicking home button

Tags: dom, caching, jquery-mobile

The order of my pages goes like this : index.html-->news.html-->newstext.html.  In my news.html page div, I enabled data-dom-cache="true" because when people come back from newstext, they are at the same page location and news.html is not refreshed.

news.html has a home button which takes it back to index where there are more topics to click on.  How can I clear news.html from the dom when the home button is clicked?

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<script>
  function clearDom(div){
    $(div).remove();}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="mainNews" data-dom-cache="true">
  <div data-theme="b" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <a onclick="clearDOM('mainNews');" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left"></a>
</div>
```

As you can see, I tried implementing the onclick method, trying to pass the divID of this page but it hasn't worked.  The only topics I found deal with not caching at all.  I want to cache until the user moves away from this page.  I think this could be very helpful to others.  Thanks for your time!

Just an update:  From clicking around on the links in news.html, on my Android phone, under cache processes, my app caches anywhere from 20 to 30 MB.  That's A LOT so I really need to clear that!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`clearDOM('#mainNews');`

You need the # for ID selectors.